# ajax call to php and return data from mysql table. Hot to make such data sturcture?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I make ajax call to php file which must read mysql and return such data structure. How to make it ?

```
[{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"0","3":"0","WtTimeFrom":"01:30:00","4":"01:30:00","WtTimeTo":"03:00:00","5":"03:00:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"1","3":"1","WtTimeFrom":"06:00:00","4":"06:00:00","WtTimeTo":"06:30:00","5":"06:30:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"1","3":"1","WtTimeFrom":"07:00:00","4":"07:00:00","WtTimeTo":"07:30:00","5":"07:30:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"1","3":"1","WtTimeFrom":"07:30:00","4":"07:30:00","WtTimeTo":"08:00:00","5":"08:00:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"1","3":"1","WtTimeFrom":"08:00:00","4":"08:00:00","WtTimeTo":"08:30:00","5":"08:30:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"2","3":"2","WtTimeFrom":"03:00:00","4":"03:00:00","WtTimeTo":"05:00:00","5":"05:00:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"2","3":"2","WtTimeFrom":"07:30:00","4":"07:30:00","WtTimeTo":"12:30:00","5":"12:30:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"3","3":"3","WtTimeFrom":"03:00:00","4":"03:00:00","WtTimeTo":"04:30:00","5":"04:30:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"3","3":"3","WtTimeFrom":"07:30:00","4":"07:30:00","WtTimeTo":"11:30:00","5":"11:30:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"3","3":"3","WtTimeFrom":"12:00:00","4":"12:00:00","WtTimeTo":"12:30:00","5":"12:30:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"3","3":"3","WtTimeFrom":"13:00:00","4":"13:00:00","WtTimeTo":"13:30:00","5":"13:30:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"3","3":"3","WtTimeFrom":"14:30:00","4":"14:30:00","WtTimeTo":"15:00:00","5":"15:00:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"4","3":"4","WtTimeFrom":"07:00:00","4":"07:00:00","WtTimeTo":"09:30:00","5":"09:30:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"4","3":"4","WtTimeFrom":"03:00:00","4":"03:00:00","WtTimeTo":"03:30:00","5":"03:30:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"}]
```

and my php file:

```
$con = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass) or die("Could not connect to database: ".mssql_get_last_message()); 
if($con){
// echo "connected";
}
// Select a database:
mssql_select_db('DB') 
    or die('Could not select a database.');

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM Details WHERE ID='2'";

// Execute query:
$result = mssql_query($SQL) 
    or die('A error occured: ' . mysql_error());
```

**How to make it in php echo such data structure ?**

Comment: mssql_connect is use to connect MSSQL not mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structure is valid JSON string.

```
[{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"0","3":"0","WtTimeFrom":"01:30:00","4":"01:30:00","WtTimeTo":"03:00:00","5":"03:00:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"1","3":"1","WtTimeFrom":"06:00:00","4":"06:00:00","WtTimeTo":"06:30:00","5":"06:30:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"1","3":"1","WtTimeFrom":"07:00:00","4":"07:00:00","WtTimeTo":"07:30:00","5":"07:30:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"1","3":"1","WtTimeFrom":"07:30:00","4":"07:30:00","WtTimeTo":"08:00:00","5":"08:00:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"1","3":"1","WtTimeFrom":"08:00:00","4":"08:00:00","WtTimeTo":"08:30:00","5":"08:30:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"2","3":"2","WtTimeFrom":"03:00:00","4":"03:00:00","WtTimeTo":"05:00:00","5":"05:00:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"2","3":"2","WtTimeFrom":"07:30:00","4":"07:30:00","WtTimeTo":"12:30:00","5":"12:30:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"3","3":"3","WtTimeFrom":"03:00:00","4":"03:00:00","WtTimeTo":"04:30:00","5":"04:30:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"3","3":"3","WtTimeFrom":"07:30:00","4":"07:30:00","WtTimeTo":"11:30:00","5":"11:30:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"3","3":"3","WtTimeFrom":"12:00:00","4":"12:00:00","WtTimeTo":"12:30:00","5":"12:30:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"3","3":"3","WtTimeFrom":"13:00:00","4":"13:00:00","WtTimeTo":"13:30:00","5":"13:30:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"3","3":"3","WtTimeFrom":"14:30:00","4":"14:30:00","WtTimeTo":"15:00:00","5":"15:00:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"4","3":"4","WtTimeFrom":"07:00:00","4":"07:00:00","WtTimeTo":"09:30:00","5":"09:30:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"},{"ID":null,"0":null,"TimeID":"2","1":"2","MyToDate":null,"2":null,"MyDayOfW":"4","3":"4","WtTimeFrom":"03:00:00","4":"03:00:00","WtTimeTo":"03:30:00","5":"03:30:00","EntryDate":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906","6":"2018:05:17 05:44:53.906"}]
```

Try to encode the result data using JSON.

```
json_encode($result);
```

Comment: JUST **$result = mssql_query($SQL)   json_encode($result);** reururn or echo  NULL